# Portlet error when upgrading Primefaces 8 to Primefaces 10

Tags: jsf, primefaces, portlet

I'm running a simple portlet on HCL Portal 9.5. Using Primefaces 8, everything worked fine, but when I use Primefaces 10, I get the following error:

```
    [26.11.2021 10:00:45:992 CET] 00000160 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service CWSRV0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause TestJSF22: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:369)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:553)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:215)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.render(PortletInvokerImpl.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doRender(ExtCollaborator.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doRender(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetPCInvokerCollaborator.doRender(IWidgetPCInvokerCollaborator.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$2.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:100)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:703)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$1.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:98)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:182)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:191)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:153)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.doRenderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:602)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.ext.render.AbstractRenderManager.performService(AbstractRenderManager.java:263)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutControlDataSource.renderPortlet(LayoutControlDataSource.java:948)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutControlDataSource.renderLayoutControl(LayoutControlDataSource.java:845)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutControlDataSource.write(LayoutControlDataSource.java:1288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wps.util.ContextWrapper$Handler.invoke(ContextWrapper.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy386.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.skin.DynamicContentSkinContentHandler.endDynamicContentSpot(DynamicContentSkinContentHandler.java:258)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.skin.RecordingSkinContentHandler.parse(RecordingSkinContentHandler.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.skin.CachingSkinURIParserImpl.parse(CachingSkinURIParserImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.parse(LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.java:286)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSource.write(LocalizedContextDataSource.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.skin.DynamicContentSkinDataSource.write(DynamicContentSkinDataSource.java:188)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.SPASkinTemplate.render(SPASkinTemplate.java:380)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.layout.rendering.DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.layoutNodeRender(DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.java:285)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.layout.rendering.DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.controlRender(DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.java:312)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.layout.rendering.DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.componentRender(DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.java:245)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.layout.rendering.DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.doFilter(DefaultPortalLayoutNodeRenderFilter.java:135)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.layout.rendering.LayoutRenderFilterChain.doFilter(LayoutRenderFilterChain.java:84)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.layout.rendering.LayoutModelRenderServiceImpl.render(LayoutModelRenderServiceImpl.java:128)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.DefaultPageRendererImpl.renderLayoutControlWithSkin(DefaultPageRendererImpl.java:1780)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.DefaultPageRendererImpl.renderLayoutControl(DefaultPageRendererImpl.java:1619)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.DefaultPageRendererImpl.renderLayoutContainer(DefaultPageRendererImpl.java:1493)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.StaticPageRendererImpl.startPortletContainer(StaticPageRendererImpl.java:3261)
    at com.ibm.portal.spa.parser.helper.AbstractStaticPageContentHandler.startPortletContainer(AbstractStaticPageContentHandler.java:449)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl$PlaybackHandler.playStartPortletContainer(CacheValueImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl$PlaybackHandler.parse(CacheValueImpl.java:425)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl$PlaybackHandler.parse(CacheValueImpl.java:400)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl.parse(CacheValueImpl.java:1434)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CachingParser.parse(CachingParser.java:550)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.StaticPageURIParserImpl.parse(StaticPageURIParserImpl.java:137)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.StaticPageURIParserImpl.parse(StaticPageURIParserImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.render(PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.java:262)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.render(PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.java:200)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.SPAScreenTemplate.render(SPAScreenTemplate.java:152)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.SPAScreenTemplate.render(SPAScreenTemplate.java:119)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.SPAScreenTemplate.render(SPAScreenTemplate.java:170)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ScreenTemplate.render(ScreenTemplate.java:59)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutTemplateDataSource.write(LayoutTemplateDataSource.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wps.util.ContextWrapper$Handler.invoke(ContextWrapper.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy375.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wps.util.ContextWrapper$Handler.invoke(ContextWrapper.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy376.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.theme.DynamicContentThemeContentHandler.endDynamicContentSpot(DynamicContentThemeContentHandler.java:350)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.theme.RecordingThemeContentHandler.parse(RecordingThemeContentHandler.java:119)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.theme.CachingThemeURIParserImpl.parse(CachingThemeURIParserImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.parse(LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.java:286)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSource.write(LocalizedContextDataSource.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.theme.DynamicContentThemeDataSource.write(DynamicContentThemeDataSource.java:186)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.tags.DataSourceTag.doEndTag(DataSourceTag.java:256)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspx_meth_r_dataSource_0(_Default.java:946)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspx_meth_c_when_0(_Default.java:972)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspService(_Default.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:553)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.doDispatch(Default.java:79)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.render(Default.java:272)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ThemeTemplate.render(ThemeTemplate.java:124)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPRenderPhase.processRendering(WPRenderPhase.java:543)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:249)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:100)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:277)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:579)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:359)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:780)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:103)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1279)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.hcl.csp.CSPFilter.doFilter(CSPFilter.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter$ExtendedFilterChain.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.SupportedLocalesFilter.doFilter(SupportedLocalesFilter.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilterWithoutProjectID(ProjectIdFilter.java:407)
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilter(ProjectIdFilter.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.doFilter(PreviewFilterImpl.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:442)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.hcl.friendlylocale.FriendlyLocaleFilter.doFilter(FriendlyLocaleFilter.java:149)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerGzip.internalDoFilter(ContentHandlerGzip.java:758)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerGzip.doFilter(ContentHandlerGzip.java:496)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.devicesupport.WorklightFilter.doFilter(WorklightFilter.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2210)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 213 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.config.PrimeConfiguration.<init>(PrimeConfiguration.java:155)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeApplicationContext.<init>(PrimeApplicationContext.java:88)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance(PrimeApplicationContext.java:221)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance(PrimeApplicationContext.java:209)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeRequestContext.getApplicationContext(PrimeRequestContext.java:199)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.<init>(PrimeFacesContext.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContextFactory.getFacesContext(PrimeFacesContextFactory.java:59)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.getFacesContext(FacesPortlet.java:788)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.doRender(FacesPortlet.java:498)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.doView(FacesPortlet.java:388)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.doDispatch(FacesPortlet.java:368)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:128)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.el.init.AttributeCopyFilter.doFilter(AttributeCopyFilter.java:158)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.capabilities.filter.PortletCapabilityDependencyFilter.doFilter(PortletCapabilityDependencyFilter.java:398)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetPortletFilter.doFilter(IWidgetPortletFilter.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.C2APortletFilter.doFilter(C2APortletFilter.java:193)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.plm.GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.doFilter(GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.filter.impl.GlobalPortletFilter.doFilter(GlobalPortletFilter.java:154)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.pcm.scoping.filter.PCMScopingFilter.doFilter(PCMScopingFilter.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:573)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doRender(PortletServletCollaborator.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doRender(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doRender(CacheCollaborator.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doRender(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:273)
    ... 212 more
```

HTML code is identical to the one posted on Primefaces "Getting started" page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <h:head>

 </h:head>

 <h:body>

     <p:spinner />

 </h:body>
```

I believe there's something wrong with Primefaces configuration (based on stack trace), but I just don't know what causes that error.

Did anyone have the same error when upgrading to PF10?

Comment: Can you try 11.0.0-RC2 please? Otherwise please create a issue, so we can fix it for final

Comment: @tandraschko I've tried with 11.0.0-RC2, but there's the same error. Thanks for your help though, I'll create an issue.